# Meaning of seal (Characters identified: 媒體勇士)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I received this in a package. Hoping someone can translate this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

The characters are

> 媒體勈（勇）⿻士八（士）

which literally translate to *media warriors*. The only thing I can find about this is a [CGTN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGTN_(TV_channel)) announcement about a competition for the next face of CGTN ("CGTN The Media Challenges"), which only happened in the last week or so (as of July 27 2021).

<sub>Did you get shortlisted for CGTN's Media Challenge?</sub>

---

**Notes on character identification**

- 「媒」 has the phonetic component 「某」. The top component of 「某」 (*plum tree*, now written as 「梅」) is [「甘」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=264) (*sweet, delicious*), depicting a *mouth* [「口」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=39) with a piece of food in it.
- 「勇」 (*courageous*) is composed of semantic 「力」 (*strength*) and phonetic 「甬」. Here, the components 「甬」 and 「力」 are written side-by-side as 「勈」.
- 「士」 is written with an obsolete variant with two extra strokes on the sides. See e.g. [小學堂傳抄古文字・士](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/chuanchao?kaiOrder=41)